# How to create a video sitemap for my website when the video is hosted on vimeo and embedded using <iframe>?

Tags: seo, video, video-sitemap

I would like to know what should be done when creating a video sitemap when the embedded player is from Vimeo?

I am very new to the SEO world and learning by doing and reading the official documentation.

For example, the video page on my website is https://bonsaiilabs.com/first-matching-dom/.

This has 1 video on a page. If you look at the source for the page, the relevant part is following

```html
<iframe title="Finding First Matching Element in DOM" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/396723555" frameBorder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" class="jss229"></iframe>
```

Now, I read the documentation about Google Video sitemap at https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/80471 and the relevant tag is see is

```html
<video:player_loc>
```

However, I do not know how to use this tag, would the following work when creating the index?

```html
<video:player_loc>
https://player.vimeo.com/video/396723555
</video:player_loc>
```

I am not sure if this is correct since the description of the  says

```
A URL pointing to a player for a specific video. Usually, this is the information in the src element of an <embed> tag. Must not be the same as the <loc> URL. For YouTube video, this value is used rather than video:content_loc. This is the equivalent of VideoObject.embedUrl in structured data.
Must not be the same as the <loc> URL.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!